# make: *** No rule to make target `wxbuild'. Stop

Tags: shell, encryption, makefile, command-line, wxwidgets

I am trying to install [ciphershed](https://wiki.ciphershed.org/BuildOnOSX) on my Mac and whenever I try to run the command

```
make wxbuild WX_ROOT=~/dev/wxMac-2.8.12
```

I get the error make: *** No rule to make target `wxbuild'.  Stop. and I can't find any good threads on solving this issue

This is the wiki I am using to install
https://wiki.ciphershed.org/BuildOnOSX

I was able to get all commands up to this point to work and all prerequisites are installed.

Comment: Your current directory is the src directory when you run the command?

Comment: @Wes : Are you sure that `Makefile` contains this target? Did you check?